# Can jQuery shorten a series of innerHTML statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my sites, I have two functions with several consecutive javascript innerHTML statements like so:

```
function myFunction(a, b, c, d, e, f, g) {
//Lots of code then
    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = b;
//Five more lines of this through parameter g
}
```

This first function has seven lines for seven parameters, and the second function has 16 lines for 16 parameters. I understand (if I use jQuery and I name each id with a numeric convention, see below) I can shorten this code as follows (function 2 as an example):

```
function myFunction2(a, b, c, .......p) {
//Lots of code then
    var z, myArray = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p];
    for (z in myArray) {
        $("#id" + (z + 1)).html(myArray[z]);//used z to avoid name collision with a through p
    } 
}
```

Is there any way I can use jQuery to do something like the following?

```
function myFunction2(a, b, c, .......p) {
//Lots of code then
    $("#id1, #id2, ....... #id16").html(a, b, c.......p);
}
```

My thinking is that each id would be matched with each parameter within the html() statement. I have not found any examples of this in my searches. I don't think this code (if it is possible) would even necessarily be better than the for loop above but it saves a couple of lines, hence the question. Thanks for any answers

Comment: How are you calling that function? If you can pass in an array things might be simpler. See Douglas Crockford. Also, if a function has "lots of code" it may be better broken into several smaller functions.

Comment: I'd stick with the for loop.  Even if it were possible to do what you're proposing, trying to line up the 16 elements in two separate lists seems like a maintenance nightmare . . .

Comment: You can do it almost identically to your third example. Just pass a function to `.html()` like this: `var a = arguments; $("#id1, #id2, ... #id16").html(function(i) { return a[i] });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope

selector $('#id1, #id2, #id3') returns an array of 3 jQuery objects

calling on them .html(...) applies that function to all selected items

edit:

also know that

```
var f = function() { console.log(arguments); };
```

when you call it

```
f(1,2,3,'a','b','c');
```

it will return

```
[1,2,3,'a','b','c']
```

so you can modify your function2:

```
function myFunction2() {
    // lots of code then
    for ( var z in arguments ) {
        $( "#id" + (z + 1) ).html( arguments[z] ); // used z to avoid name collision with a through p
    } 
}
```

good luck!

Comment: `$('#id1, #id2, #id3')` doesn't return an array of 3 jQuery objects. It returns a single jQuery object with 3 DOM Elements.

Answer (score 4):

If your IDs really are numerically named, you don't need jQuery to shorten things:

```
function myFunction2(/* don't need the parameter list */) {
  //Lots of code then

  for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i )
  {
    document.getElementById( 'id' + (i + 1) ).innerHTML = arguments[i];
  }
}
```

Or pass in a prefix to use it for different sets of IDs, all depending on the number of parameters passed:

```
function myFunction2(prefix) {
  //Lots of code then

  for ( var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i )
  {
    document.getElementById( prefix + i ).innerHTML = arguments[i];
  }
}

myFunction2('id', "a", "b", "c");  // sets #id1, #id2, #id3 to a, b, c
myFunction2('other", "x", "y");    // sets #other1, #other2 to x, y
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function thing() {
    $.each(arguments, function(n, val) {
        $('#id'+ (n+1)).html(val);
    });
}
```

then

`thing('first', 'second', 'third', .... 'millionth')`

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately the html method only accepts zero or one parameter. You *can* write a selector which will target various different DOM elements, but they will all be passed the same parameters from your html() call. If you want to get a little creative, you can pass html() a function whose logic can depend on some property or attribute of the parent element, but that's not going to save you many keystrokes in the end.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to @PaulRoub's but in this function you can pass the starting index ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/mxweK/1/)):

```
function myFunction(start) {
    var i,
        arg = arguments,
        len = arg.length;
    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        $("#id" + (start + i)).html(arg[i]);
    }
}

myFunction( 1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' );
```

Comment: Oops, I guess I'm passing an array as the second argument.